# How to dynamically add a program's library path to @INC in Perl program?

Tags: perl

I'm working on an application that is written in Perl. The application is so large now that I want to move each class out into a separate file. This complicated building and installing the program; when it was only file it could easily be copied in place anywhere. Now I have to use a build system like `Build::Module` or `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`.

I have structured my source tree so that I have two directories: `bin` where the program launcher is, and `lib` where a number of modules are. `Bin` contains an executable Perl script which the user invokes, and it loads the necessary module from the lib directory.

The problem that I have is that I want the user to be able to specify a prefix where they want the program installed, similar to the `--prefix` option offered by packages based on GNU Autotools. Since this might not be a standard path where Perl looks for modules (for example /opt/program) the user will see a message saying something like `Can't locate Program.pm in @INC`.

Is there a way to make the program detect where the modules should be loaded frm and dynamically add that path to `@INC`? I don't want the user to have to manually work with environment variables like `PERL5LIB` in order to get the program running.

Comment: Unclear: how would the user communicate the install location to the program? Not via environment variables, so maybe with a command line option or a registry setting? Or should the program search the disks by itself?

Comment: Preferably via some kind of build system. For example the user can already add something like --prefix=/opt/program when running Makefile.PL to install it in that directory. All I need is a way to pick that up in the launcher script, for example a preprocessing step that adds the use lib line to the installed file.

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you use [findbin](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html) and [lib](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) ?:

```
use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib "$Bin/lib";
```

Comment: `$RealBin` is better than `$Bin` since it works when you use symbolic links.

Comment: @ikegami: I just create symlink: `ln -s tmp/del/my_app/script sym; cd sym; ./test.pl` with code: `print "$FindBin::Bin $FindBin::RealBin"` which prints: `/home/kes/tmp/del/my_app/script /home/kes/tmp/del/my_app/script`. It seems both variables work similar, thought documentation does not say so.

Comment: @Eugen Konkov, `$Bin` gives the wrong directory when you link to the script. [Example](https://pastebin.com/raw/frNu34h7)

Comment: @ikegami: Now I see the difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, you're breaking up a big large program into smaller components. Good for you! That's great programming technique. Making each class a true Perl module is a great idea. It makes your program so much easier to maintain.

I do this all of the time. First, I use the module name `Local::` as my prefix. CPAN will never use `Local` as a module prefix, so I know I will never clash with some CPAN Module. Then, I put my `Local` module directory in the same directory as my script. In most standard Perl installations, when Perl searches `@INC` for modules, the last directory it searches for is the current directory (`.`). Since my module names will never clash with any CPAN modules, I know Perl will find my modules and only my modules under that `./Local` directory.

You can now distribute the entire directory structure to other users. All a user has to do is install your entire directory (which includes the scripts and modules) and run the script. No need to go through an entire install process.

Answer (score 0):

The  following code works for me. You supply a command line option like (--prefix abc) and that value is appended to the lib path very early in your script. So all following modules will be searched with the dynamically set path.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my $prefix = '';

BEGIN {
  GetOptions ('prefix=s' => \$prefix );
  $prefix = $prefix || '.';
}

use lib "$prefix";
use mymod; # uses the dynamical search path
```

Comment: I believe they were wanting --prefix at build/install time, not runtime.

Comment: @ysth: Ok, on second reading I agree. Then I would not call it 'dynamically', though.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your main program script (NOT your .pm files) include the following lines near the top.

```perl
# This prepends to the module load path.
use FindBin qw//;
use lib "$FindBin::RealBin/lib";
```

Any modules loaded BELOW those lines will come FIRST from the local 'lib' directory.

```perl
# Loads from lib/MyLocalLib/MyClass.pm
require MyLocalLib::MyClass;
```

How `FindBin` works is the first time it's loaded via `use`, it sets `$FindBin::RealBin` to the directory name of the currently executing script (`$0`). `FindBin` *should* ship with Perl.

You'll want to use `$FindBin::RealBin` and not `$FindBin::Bin` in case your script is executing from a symbolic link. (e.g. you symlinked it to `/usr/bin/myprogram.pl`). If you use `$FindBin::Bin`, it'll try loading from `/usr/bin/lib/`.

## TMTOWTDI

If you prefer a less-robust solution, the following method will do the more-or-less the same thing as above:

```perl
use File::Basename 'dirname';
use Cwd 'abs_path';
use lib dirname(abs_path($0)) . '/lib';
```